# Find the value of $S$ using a more mathematical method

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> If $$A=\int_0^1(1-x^{2023})^{\frac{1}{2022}}dx$$ and $$B=\int_0^1(1-x^{2022})^{\frac{1}{2023}}dx$$ then find the value of $S$ if  $$S=\frac{A^3-B^3}{B^3}+\frac{A^4+B^4}{B^4}$$

---

Now I have solved this question by using the definition of integration. We can treat integration as a continuous summation, so the value of both $A$ and $B$ is approximately $1$ as all other terms contribute negligible to the sum. So we get $S=2$.

---

I was wondering whether there is any other more mathematical method. I tried substituting $(1-x^{2023})^{\frac{1}{2022}}$ as $t$ but nothing good happened. I can't think of any other method. Maybe expanding the function can help, but how can I even expand this.

Ant help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In simpler terms: you want the value of $A/B$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function ?

Comment: Could you explain "the value of both A and B is approximately 1 as all other terms contribute negligible to the sum" in more detail?

Comment: @Stef the integrals geometrically represent the area of [this curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E%282022%29+%2B+y%5E%282023%29+%3D+1), which is approximately a box. The corrections to the box shape were considered negligible by OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that

$$y = f(x) = (1-x^{2023})^{\frac{1}{2022}} \implies x = f^{-1}(y) = (1-y^{2022})^{\frac{1}{2023}}$$

And since both functions are decreasing on $(0,1)$ with $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$, geometrically this means that we have

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx = \int_0^1f^{-1}(y)dy$$

by simply flipping our perspective of the graph by $90^\circ$. Thus $A=B$ and

$$S = \frac{A^3}{B^3} + \frac{A^4}{B^4} = 2$$

Comment: This is phenomenal

Comment: Can you pls elaborate more how are they equal..maybe with a help of a diagram...I get what u r trying to say but I am having difficulty in visualising it

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad The inverse of a function is symmetrical about the line $y=x$.

Comment: Excellent solution..

Answer (score 2):

Another way. Exercise in special functions.

For $n,m>0$, we can show that
$$I_{m,n}=\int_0^{1}(1-x^n)^{\frac1m}\,dx=(1+\tfrac1m+\tfrac1n)B(1+\frac1m,1+\frac1n)=\frac{\Gamma(1+\frac1m)\Gamma(1+\frac1n)}{\Gamma(\tfrac1n+1+\tfrac1m)}.$$

Hint: $u=x^n$ substitution. See the [output](https://Hint:%20%7B7c50e718-4499-4fef-b9a5-70478a8777bd%7D%20substitution.%20See%20the%20%5Boutput%5D%5B1%5D%20of%20WolframAlpha.) of WolframAlpha.

Since the expression is symmetric in $n,m$, we have $I_{m,n}=I_{n,m}$. In particular, $I_{2023,2022}=_{2022,2023}$, that is $A=B.$ Hence
$$S=\frac{A^3-B^3}{B^3}+\frac{A^4+B^4}{B^4}=(\tfrac AB)^3-1+(\tfrac AB)^4+1=1^3-1+1^4+1=2.$$

Comment: Your integral for $I_{m,n}$ should simplify to $\frac{1}{n} \mathrm{B}(1/n,1/m)$ rather than $\mathrm{B}(1/n,1/n)$.

Comment: @dmk Thanks. As I wrote now. Right..?

Comment: I think we're both getting thrown off by the notation, since I made a mistake earlier as well. According to your substitution, we should have $\int_0^1(1-x^n)^{1/m}dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1u^{1/n-1}(1-u)^{1/m}du=\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{B}(1/n,\mathbf{1/m+1})$. Using the fact that $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$, your result follows. Let me know what you think :).

Comment: I did use the result of WA not my substitution. @dmk laziness.